# Log4J2 property substitution - with an external properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

in my application, i have an external properties file, and im trying to use this file in defining some properties in my log4J2.xml

does anyone have an idea how to do that ?

thanks in advance.

[Edited]

i think my question wasn't clear, i have springboot module that uses a an external properties file instead of the application.properties. the probleme is that when i do this ${bundle:application:file.name} it worked, but now with the application.properties changed to another location (say D:/myProperties.properties) my log4j2.xml doesn't recognize the property "myFileName".

Answer (score 0):

You can use property substitution, Log4j 2 supports the ability to specify tokens in the configuration as references to properties defined elsewhere. 
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution

```
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Appenders>
        <Appender type="File" name="File"
                  fileName="${sys:testAppLogPath:-default/location/of/testApp.log}">

    </Appenders>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Use EnvironmentLookup allows to configure environment variables, either in global files  or in the startup scripts for applications, and then retrieve those variables from within the logging configuration. $${env:USER}